# Change font in Beamer to a more modern, sleek font

Tags: beamer, fonts

I noticed that many of today's presentations (not done by Beamer) use modern-looking, sleek fonts. Is it possible to set Beamer's fonts to use such fonts? All the current fonts in Beamer look a bit dated...

Thanks.

Comment: You can use any font package. Have a look at the [font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/). Using XeTeX or LuaTeX you can also use system fonts.

Comment: @ido What did you decide to use?

Comment: @Johannes_B Can you turn your comment into an answer, perhaps giving an example of how to load a suitable package?

Comment: @cfr I'm on it.

Comment: @cfr I used iwona. By the way, there was some error after downloading the font. Running "MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\updmap.exe" fixed it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use any font provided by a LaTeX package. You can see a list at the [LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
    adieresis={ä},
    germandbls={ß}
}
\newcommand{\testtext}{The
    quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\\
ä Ä ß }
%Loading a font package, uncomment one of the following lines to see changes
%\usepackage{tgheros}
%\usepackage{tgadventor}
%\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A sample frame}
    \testtext
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Using modern engines like Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX you can use OpenType and TrueType fonts installed on your system using package `fontspec`. You can easily change a font within the document. A quite silly example follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\testtext}{The
    quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\\
ä Ä ß }
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    %setting a font
    \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A sample frame}
    \testtext
\end{frame}
    \setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\begin{frame}{Another sample frame}
    \testtext
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Please be aware, that those engines (Xe/LuaTex) have native utf8 support and even request the input to be saved in utf8 by default.

Comment: What command will compile your second example please?

Comment: @user4417 Usually, you do `pdflatex mainfile`. Now you would do `xelatex mainfile` or `lualatex mainfile`.

Comment: Thanks. `xelatex` worked straight away, but `lualatex` was telling me it couldn't find luaotfload.sty. I installed texlive-luatex and all is good.