# Blackboard handwritten presentation slides

Tags: beamer, presentations, blackboard, slideshow

I found there is a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162873/i-need-a-beamer-theme-simulating-blackboard-presentation). Forgive me since I don't quite like the answer given there—the font, the format, etc.

What I want is something like the one given [here](https://folk.ntnu.no/gereonq/Presentation_NMF_Bergen_2018.pdf). I think it's of the same kind as Michael Hopkins's (one can search YouTube to see Michael Hopkins's slides).

I'm very grateful if anyone can tell how to make that kind of [slides](https://folk.ntnu.no/gereonq/Presentation_NMF_Bergen_2018.pdf), or better, give a template for the slides as an answer. I even don't know if it is made by LaTeX; so if it is produced by some other thing, please tell me what it is, then I can learn how to use it.

(I also want to know how to make the beautiful pictures like the sphere, torus, higher genus surfaces etc. with various colours and submanifolds etc.)

Comment: Tori can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348/194703) and also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478542/194703).

Comment: Thanks for tori!

Comment: For the fonts, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154350/101651

Comment: @CarLaTeX How about the slides itself?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The main thing I want is the slides like this: https://folk.ntnu.no/gereonq/Presentation_NMF_Bergen_2018.pdf

Comment: To change the font, see the link to my previous comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154350/change-font-in-beamer-to-a-more-modern-sleek-font. If you have some problems, please add a complete but minimal example to you question: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that