# Change Font for a \newcommand (cyrilic)

Tags: fonts, macros, cyrillic

I had to

I had to define (because of beamer and interference with other languages) the environment for Cyrillic. How can I now make the Cyrillic appear in a nicer Cyrilic font?

MWE:

````
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[OT2, T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\textcyr}[1]{
{\donothyphenate\fontencoding{OT2}\selectfont #1}}
\newlanguage\nohyphens\newcommand{\donothyphenate}{
\language=\nohyphens}

\begin{document}

Russia \textcyr{izmenitp1}  \emph{izmenit} (tr.) ‘change’ 
 
\end{document}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `babel` for disabling hyphenation, but your method is good as well.

The key is to use the font family `wncyr` that has Type1 fonts compatible with Computer Modern, if you're tied to transliterated input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[base]{babel}

\usepackage[OT2, T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{OT2}{cmr}{wncyr}
\newcommand{\textcyr}[1]{%
  \begin{hyphenrules}{nohyphenation}%
    \fontencoding{OT2}\selectfont #1%
  \end{hyphenrules}%
}

\begin{document}

Russian \textcyr{izmenitp1} \emph{izmenit} (tr.) ‘change’

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed. Thaks!

Answer (score 2):

The approach in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215454/ works also for `beamer`. I'm not sure this fits your requirements but maybe it can be a starting point. The font is similar to Times. The MWE below shows sans serif (default in `beamer`) and serif (using the `\rmfamily` font switch).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{paratype}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{T2A}{\rmdefault}{PTSerif-TLF}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Russian in \texttt{beamer}}
Russia изменить \emph{izmenit} (tr.) ‘change’ 

\rmfamily Russia изменить \emph{izmenit} (tr.) ‘change’
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that you have the option of choosing an arbitrary font if you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, see for example the second part of the answer in [Change font in Beamer to a more modern, sleek font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154350/change-font-in-beamer-to-a-more-modern-sleek-font).